# Time Data From Nest API In Correct Format?

Tags: nest-api

I have noticed that the date and time fields being returned to me from the Nest API are not matching the format that the API documentation lists.

For my thermostat, I am getting the following for last_connection:

"last_connection": "2014-10-27T20:22:12.165Z"

But the API documentation lists it should be formatted as:

"last_connection": "2014-10-27T20:22:12+06:00"

Why is the Nest API returning milliseconds to me and why am I getting the character "Z" instead of the actual timezone offset that the date/time is coming from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the example is incorrect with respect to the actual implementation. If you look at the [API Reference](https://developer.nest.com/documentation/api-reference) you will see the time data is all in [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), which support both string types.

This also means you should likely use a library to support ISO 8601, rather than manually parsing the string if possible.

Comment: Java 1.6 (requirement) has no ISO 8601 implementation and I don't want to rely on external libraries. I decided I'm just going to manually handle the Z case by replacing it with "GMT-0:00" and checking to insert "GMT" when an actual timezone is given. Appears to work, but may break in the future I guess.